# Is the IMAP UID always numeric?

Tags: imap

Is the IMAP UID guaranteed numeric? I've read the part in RFC3501 and it says:

> Unique identifiers
>      are assigned in a strictly ascending fashion in the mailbox; as each
>      message is added to the mailbox it is assigned a higher UID than the
>      message(s) which were added previously.

But could it be that the UID has a pre- or postfix? For example, could it be that the UID is mail_14 and the next msg mail_15?

Answer: IMAP UID is a unique nonzero integer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to read the part in RFC3501 that defines the UID:

```
uniqueid        = nz-number
                ; Strictly ascending
```

Page 91.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume "nz" stands for "nonzero"?

Comment: The definition of nz-number is on page 88.